# Chat Enhancement

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I'm one of the Chat Room Owners, in which you usually have people who come in and request assistance.  Some of the usual people have conversations about encounters, but every so often an individual:

- Takes quite a bit of time explaining and helping an individual.
- Provides stellar information.
- Clarifies misnomers and additional information for learning.

These type of people, get rewarded for such an exemplary job on Stack Overflow. **Why don't we implement such a capability on Chat?** To avoid abuse, I thought of the following:

- Only people who answer may receive either a reputation boost.
- Maximum gain is thirty reputation within a twenty four hour period.
- When someone is nominated two additional people must also agree it is worthy.
- When someone is nominated, the nominated and nominator can't be among the two additional people.

Just some feedback, I've noticed several of those people here at Stack Overflow and those are the people we should try to keep within the community.  Those mentors are what makes Stack Overflow such a wonderful place.

Comment: Comments can provide the same information, but those don't go for reputation either <_<

Comment: @Compass Maybe we should overhaul that as well.

Comment: @Compass In fairness to that statement, there is no "Post Answer" button anywhere in chat. I would love to see a way of reversing the "answering in comments" trend though.

Comment: Comments are already considered chit-chat, adding chat to that doesn't seem wise. Wouldn't it be better to ask the one who wants to learn to post a question on SO (maybe with the assistence of the room) so both the question and answer can be edited in to shape back-and-forth between main site and chat while the end result is available on the main site and regular quality control and getting credits kicks in?